# Number of element of order $5$ in $ S_5$.

Tags: group-theory

What is the number of element of order $5$ in $ S_5$ ?

I think there is only the 5-cycle, but how can I show it ?

Comment: The $5$-cycle$\color{red}{s}$. Use the decomposition of any permutation as a product of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 1):

All elements of order $5$ are in the $5-$Sylow group. Let $n$ be the number of $5-$sylow group. Then, $$n\mid 24\quad \text{and}\quad n\equiv 1\pmod 5.$$ So $n=6$. All elements except the identity of those Sylow group are of order 5 (why ?), so there is $6\cdot 5-6=24$ elements of order $5$. So your result is correct since there are $(5-1)!=4!=24$ cycle of length $5$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* All $5$-cycles have order $5$.